# Json Post works in Postman but not in C#

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

When I try the Post request in Postman it gives me the right response with no error. When I use the generated Restsharp code from Postman the response is always empty with no error.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://myurl/api/authenticate/authenticate");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("postman-token", "00497e4f-f58f-677d-f98a-bb972032c2eb");
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"applicationKey\" : \"MYAPPLICATIONKEY\",\n\t\"userSecret\" : \"MYUSERSECRET\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

I tried to delete the lines with postman-token, cache-control but always the same no error no response. (In the response I should get the access token)

Comment: Do you use your own server certificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But I also think you may have an issue as you are passing the body as JSON, and RestSharp will try to serialise it into JSON again. Try this.

Make a class to hold your parameters

```
 public class Body
 {
    public string applicationKey { get; set; }
    public string userSecret { get; set; }
 }
```

and pass it as the parameter content

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://myurl");
 var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);  
 request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
 request.Resource = "api/authenticate/authenticate";

 var body = new Body();
 body.applicationKey = "MYAPPLICATIONKEY";
 body.userSecret = "MYUSERSECRET";

 request.AddBody(body);
 IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
 Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

turned out it was TLS version issue.

Fixed by adding

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

before the call.

Comment: still the same there is nothing in response.Content and no error Message.... should I add charset=UTF-8 somewhere?

Comment: I'd view your request and the response using Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), and see if you can spot anything. You should be able to find a guide to using Fiddler online easy enough.

Comment: ok I put my code there and it gives me this error: {"Cause":"Unable to execute the REST operation","Detail":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse the given input stream as JSON document

Comment: can you try my edits above, thats taken from my code which does work

Comment: ok I´ve put it into fiddle and I am getting a html error "Unable to process request... The requestet service does not exist"

Comment: get rid of the Resource part and go back to your original URL

Comment: my bad I put the wrong URL (still with api/authenticate/authenticate) now its working in fiddle. I get the access_token. But when I copy this code to visual studio I have an empty response

Comment: I said to use http://www.telerik.com/fiddler, its a web debugger, so you can view your request from Visual studio and get more info about what is wrong.

Comment: In Fiddler the console application sends 2 requests and postman only 1. See here [link](http://imgur.com/a/aWmlD)

Comment: I found this error in fiddler  HTTPS handshake to myurl (for #1166) failed. System.IO.IOException

Comment: ok. could be TLS versions, add this line at start of main ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

Comment: now I´m getting my access token :) Wow so I just put this before every request I make? Thank you ajg for your patience and your awesome help. Have a nice day!

Comment: cool, I'll edit the answer so its not just in the comments. You only need to do it once, so find a good place for it (constructor or wherever).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this only for test:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
            {
               return true;
            };
     //...
     //Your Rest Call
 }
```

For internal usage, you can do:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=  (sender, cert, chain, error) =>
{
     return cert.GetCertHashString() == "server certificate hash";
};
```

Comment: If you use console app then in main

Comment: I copied this between IrestResponse and Console.Writeline but when I debug its just the same empty message

Comment: It must be before your restserver call

Comment: IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request); but place it before var client = new RestClient("https://myurl/api/authenticate/authenticate");

Comment: still the same no message nothing (btw thanks for the patience and help)